# Model and code for longitudinal RCT analysis

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data, baseline

I have been given a dataset involving participants (`ID`) at different `sites` who were randomly allocated to one of two `conditions`. So there are several sites in one condition and other sites in the other condition (think this is a cluster-RCT). The participants were assessed for a continuous `outcome` at three timepoints (pre-intervention, post-intervention, and follow-up). There is also a three-level demographic variable to control for (`covar1`). I think a longitudinal mixed model is what is required but I just wanted to check the approach and the code.

I have also read that controlling for baseline scores is important. So my understanding is that the outcome data in the model would only involve measures at the second and third timepoint given that the first is involved in the model a `baseline` covariate.

I also imagine random intercepts makes sense for both IDs and site.

With these things in mind, does the following make sense?

```r
model <- lmer(outcome ~ condition + time + condition*time + baseline + 
                         covar1 + (1|site/ID)
```

From some exploratory plots, I noticed differing slopes for sites, so perhaps this should be incorporated too? If so, would this involve a further `(time|site)` ?

Does this sound generally ok? I've run simple longitudinal models before but just wanted to check this approach, especially after seeing differing model specs inc. some involving an interaction between time*baseline as well as a baseline main effect.